# Angularjs : How to restrict user inputs which contain sql query keywords (for sql injection)

Tags: javascript, sql, angularjs, sql-injection

I have a requirement in AngularJs project on login and other form, to restrict user inputs which contain specific keywords like "SELECT","INSERT", "UPDATE", DELETE","DROP" etc in input fields. This will help us prevent SQL injection attacks.

Please let me know if we have any angularjs library to accomplish this. Or how can this be achieved efficiently using angularjs?

Thanks.

Comment: What library do you use for working with SQL database?

Comment: We are using MySQL database and communicate with DB using Restful webservices.

Comment: Whatever way you do this you must do it server side as well. In my opinion you'd be better allowing them client side and ensuring you do a good job using parameters server side. If someone want's to call them selves Mr Drop then that's fine.

Comment: *"This will help us prevent SQL injection attacks."* Nope, it will not.

Comment: It's not user friendly, really. What if my last name is `Insert`. Jake Insert. Why not?

Comment: Yes we can have server validation on query parameters. It would be great if we catch user inputs like "Delete * From <Table_Name> where 1=1" and prevent DB call. How can we do this in angularjs?

Comment: @sandeepk Really, [read up on the topic off SQL-injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Guide_to_SQL_Injection) in general and you'll soon realise that this is not something you do on the client side. The whole effort is simply in vain. If you want to invest time, do it right from the start.

Comment: I know we cannot complete avoid SQL injection by just having client side validation in angularjs but we want to stop such malicious calls on front-end only without even making call to server. Can we do this in angularjs?

Comment: take a breath and rethink the whole thing. Just add a captcha ...

Answer (score 1):

1. Black list is NOT the answer in security. If you check for the word "select", the attacker will inject "sElEct" or "sel/**/ect" (in MySQL). If you split the words with spaces, the attacker will use comments ("/**/") or tabs as delimiters. You can never win with the black list approach (especially with whole words as you suggested), always use white list approach and allow only permitted characters (a-z,A-Z,0-9 for example).
2. Any client-side validation is bound to fail. An attacker can easily attack any Javascript-based "Defenses" with any simple proxy such as fiddler or burp. You should implement your **white list** input validation in your server side code alongside parametrized queries or some other best-practice to prevent SQL Injection in the DAL level (both are recommended together).